# Behringer xenyx 2222fx

Tags: audio

I could use some help with getting my mixer to work. I have a *[Behringer xenyx 2222fx](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiOyvKb2p_LAhWLtBoKHdoWBQoQFghdMAc&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2FBehringer-2222FX-22-Input-Mixer-Effects%2Fdp%2FB000J621PM&usg=AFQjCNFATWYLL9_mKtq-lov9bDAjHTN55A&sig2=2qPzPCfvMQwhwf-hp2tuVQ)* and a pair of *[krk rokit 5 g3 monitors](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiH_5232p_LAhUH0xoKHW1JBBkQFgg8MAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.krksys.com%2Fkrk-studio-monitor-speakers%2Frokit%2Frokit-5.html&usg=AFQjCNHZmwzmnNMCXIkTnavA7GmVyqTS1g&sig2=qdsj4zUzca6auxFsczXwKA)*.

I have both speakers connected to the main output ports on the back of the mixer and I have the mixer connected to my computer via USB, and the power supply is of course plugged in.

My problem is I can't figure out *how to get sound out of the speakers*.

When I push the master faders all the way up all I hear is white noise yet my music is playing on the laptop. I just can't hear it.

I'm not sure what buttons on the mixer itself have to be pressed to get it working.

Comment: What OS are you using? If Windows, open the Plackback (Control panel -> sound) and ensure your USB is detected and set as default

Comment: If you have audio out from the laptop when you use headphones, then there isn't much we can do for you since sound mixing boards and PA systems are off topic here.

Comment: There is a SE site for this - [sound.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first turn the main out right down and the monitor levels right down so you don't hear static , if you hear static that means your speakers are turened up seriously loud or something is adding a lot gain.

if you just want to hear one track of output then enable Post Fader Listen on that channel to do that. Otherwise have a look at the toggle button next to the main faders , it should switch between the groups and PFL.

Each channel will have an input gain , the idea here is to get all your signals into the mix at the same level and with the same amount of headroom. Then use the channel faders to adjust the relative level in the mix. try to keep the input gain low as it will add noise if its too high.
there are usually red clipping lights to show you if the level is too high

the lights on the main channel should show you if there is signal, ideally you want to use them to find the signal and then when you know its playing gradually increase the main faders or monitor levels. Be prepared to suddently turn it down as it could be very loud. (word to the wise: don't hold a drink when doing this). I usually do this with some headphones plugged in but not on my head and the speakers/amps off , you can hear when a signal is coming but not deafen yourself.

your mixer will mix to groups and then to a stereo pair , for various reasons you might want that stereo pair to go to the speakers or a recorder. This flexibility is a good thing even if it feels like a pain right now.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I appreciate the help and you taking the time to explain.